# ASP.Net Gridview not rebind data on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

i am new in asp.net i using LINQ with asp.net on button click event my gridview not rebind data and yes gridview is into the updatepanel

'>
                                                        
                                                    
                                                    
                                                        
                                                            '>

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvClientData.Rows)
    {

        if (((CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("chkdisplay")).Checked == true)
        {
            string Index = ((Label)gvr.FindControl("lblIndex")).Text;
            int GIIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Index);
            GI_InsureMaster insertclientinfo = vjdb.GI_InsureMasters.Single(upd => upd.GIMastIndex == GIIndex);
            insertclientinfo.SendToCompany = true;
            vjdb.SubmitChanges();
        }

    }
    BindAgencyData();
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
}
```

Comment: You left the more important method `BindAgencyData` from your code.

Comment: What do you mean with "rebind data"? If you are missing data in you save method then please keep in mind, that you have to rebind your gridview in page_load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to modify an object and then saving it back to the DB, but you are doing it wrong.

You are querying the object from a different Data Context, `vjdb` and you are calling `SubmitChanges` on `linqobject`. You should call `SubmitChanges` on `vjdb`

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvClientData.Rows)
    {

        if (((CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("chkdisplay")).Checked == true)
        {
            string Index = ((Label)gvr.FindControl("lblIndex")).Text;
            int GIIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Index);
            GI_InsureMaster insertclientinfo = vjdb.GI_InsureMasters.Single(upd => upd.GIMastIndex == GIIndex);
            insertclientinfo.SendToCompany = true;
            vjdb.SubmitChanges(); //HERE
        }

    }
    BindAgencyData();
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
}
```

*Assuming that `BindAgencyData` is querying database for latest/updated record and then binding the data to the grid.*